# How do you expand acronyms (e.g. "is" = Information Specialist) while leaving the same word with different context unexpanded (e.g. "is")?

Tags: python, text

I'm working on a project in which I have to expand our domain-specific acronyms, such as "IS" (Information Specialist). However, the current script I have also expands common words, such as "is" (e.g. He is funny). How could I differentiate between whether or not the word is actually an acronym?

Currently, I am using a dictionary, with the keys as the acronyms and the values as the expanded versions of the acronyms.

EDIT: I should have specified that I am more concerned about edge cases in which the acronyms aren't capitalized and don't have periods between the letters.

Comment: Acronyms are usually CAPITALIZED, so you can use the case of the letters to differentiate them.

Comment: @martineau I was more concerned about the edge cases in which they aren't capitalized and don't have periods in between the letters

Comment: I suggest you just do the best you can using a well-defined pattern with perhaps a small number of variations (like allowing the periods to be optional).

Comment: A good question, not sure why the downvotes. Happens quite often in reality when people are too lazy to capitalize acronyms or simply data issue. You can look at context. In simple cases, If "is" looks like a verb in the context, don't expand. If not, expand. In more complex cases, you may need text analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure whatever you do is case-sensitive. You should also check for `.` in-between characters.

I would split on each word in the string, look for ones that are all caps and only apply the dictionary to those words. Alternatively you could use a global regex find/replace to do similar and it could look for both "IS" and "I.S.".

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the words in a list then check if any of the words are in all CAPS then compare it with your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the acronyms are all capitalized you can just do a really simple split and compare.

```
def expand(string, dict):
    tokens = string.split(" ")
    for token in tokens:
        if token in dict:
            yield dict[token]
        else:
            yield token

d = {"IS":"Informatoin Specialist","SO":"Stack Overflow"}
s = "John is an IS at SO"

print(*[t for t in expand(s,d)])

#John is an Information Specialist at Stack Overflow
```